# How to change the direction of arrows on Feynman diagrams in LaTeX?

Tags: software

I am having a lot of difficulty writing Feynman diagrams in LaTeX. In particular, getting the direction of arrows correct for my external fermion lines. On overleaf I used the code they wrote as an example:

```
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
  a -- [photon] b,
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};
```

I should get the following output[image: Overleafs Feynman diagram]

Instead overleaf gives me this:[image]

How can I change the direction of my external fermion lines??

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: I agree. That's why we migrated the question ...

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse the arrows by switching from `fermion`s to `anti fermion`s. When I compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] { 
i1 -- [anti fermion] a -- [anti fermion] i2, a -- [photon] b,
 f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2, };
\end{document}
```

with `lualatex` I get

[image]